# Getting Realm Notifications in In-Memory Realms

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Hey there I do have a question that somebody might answer me without having to write a single line of code :) I am using Realm for Swift and wanted to avoid persisting data. This is why I tried to use In-Memory Realms. This works fine but Notifications for Realm are not firing if I use In-Memory. If I use the regular version with persisting data it works. On the Realm website they say that

> In-memory Realms do not save data across app launches, but all other features of Realm will work as expected, including querying, relationships and thread-safety

Is this a bug or is this intended that notifications do not work? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

Here is my code

```
var token: NotificationToken?
public let realm = try! Realm()
//public let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
token = realm.addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
            // Update your user interface, reload your table, rest easy
            print("Fire AddNotificationBlock")
            self.reloadTableData()
        }
}

deinit{
        token?.stop()
    }
```

This is my implementation when I use persistent storage. For switching to in-memory I switched the realm variables you can see on the top. I thought that this would be all you have to do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Notifications should work also in-memory Realms. Can you please share your code?